# Invertible matrices, permutations and leading principal minors

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, determinant

Given an invertible $\{-1,0,1\}$-matrix $A$ (its determinant is $\pm 1$), are there two permutation matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that all the leading principal minors (determinants of the top-left sub-matrices) of $A' = P A Q$ are $\pm 1$?

For example, 
$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right], \quad \det(A) = 1 $$
and
$$
A' = 
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
\cdot A \cdot
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right]
$$
accomplishes the condition.

Comment: Consider $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.  No permutation of rows and columns will make the leading principal $1\times 1$ minor be $\pm 1$.

Comment: Thank you @hardmath. I wanted to consider all the integer matrices. Given your counter-example, I edited the question to restrict the problem only for the matrices with entries in {-1,0,1}